# How can I create a planner task with a description?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API with the .Net SDK.

I'm trying to create a new PlannerTask, and provide a description with it when doing that.

The description for a PlannerTask is on a related object, PlannerTaskDetails, and so that object is "read-only".

This seems to imply that to create a PlannerTask with a Description I have to make at least two calls. The first call creates the PlannerTask, and the second call updates the PlannerTaskDetails.

To update the PlannerTaskDetails, an e-tag is needed. So I used Expand to request that the Details property is populated when returning the created PlannerTask. But it is returned unpopulated (i.e. null).

```
var task = await graphServiceClient
    .Planner
    .Tasks
    .Request()
    .Expand("Details")
    .AddAsync(plannerTask);

var taskPlannerDetailsETag = task.Details.GetEtag();

var taskDetails = await graphServiceClient
    .Planner
    .Tasks[task.Id]
    .Details
    .Request()
    .Header("If-Match", taskPlannerDetailsETag)
    .UpdateAsync(new PlannerTaskDetails()
    {
        Description = officeTask.Body
    });
```

So the next thing to try would be creating the PlannerTask, then making a second call to retrieve the PlannerTaskDetails, and then a third call to update the PlannerTaskDetails. But I think I must be approaching this wrong, 3 network round trips to create a single task with a description seems, well, absurd.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous reply is outdated. You can set task details fields in the same request as creating the task, and you can also immediately read an item after the create request.

> Creating a task, reading the details, then updating the details is
> currently the correct way of accomplishing this scenario. Note that
> reading the details immediately after creating the task may fail, as
> the processing is asynchronous, so you should add some retry logic to
> have stable behavior. We're working on improvements on this scenario
> to simplify the process.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I can move on now I know this is the process that needs to be done. And thanks for the hint about the retry logic, that's very useful to know.

Comment: Note: If you want to return the latest TaskDetails object along with the Task, you actually need 4 calls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866395/updating-taskdetails-silently-fails/48866666#48866666