# Updating PlannerTaskDetails silently fails

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph .Net SDK to interact with Planner.
I've just created a `PlannerTask`, and I'd like to set the Description property.

My approach for this is covered in: [How can I create a planner task with a description?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851611/how-can-i-create-a-planner-task-with-a-description)

Here's the code which takes the returned `PlannerTaskDetails` object, modifies the Description, and then updates it:

```
var taskDetails = taskDetailsResult.Result; // Get Previous Task Details
taskDetails.Description = description;

task.Details = await graphServiceClient
    .Planner
    .Tasks[task.Id]
    .Details
    .Request()
    .Header("If-Match", taskDetails.GetEtag())
    .UpdateAsync(taskDetails);
```

UpdateAsync returns, but it returns a null.
There's no exception, the null obviously contains no further information, and the Description is not changed.

I used Fiddler to monitor the HTTP traffic going back and forth. I can see that a `PATCH` request is being sent to the Graph API, and it has the `If-Match` header set.

Oddly, the JSON object in the request body has the description property listed twice! The first time with my value, and the second time with a null.

I assume the deserializer is taking the last value it sees for a property, and so that's why it doesn't update.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly changed your code to use a patch object instead of reusing the existing `PlannerTaskDetail`. To get back the updated object (if this is supported), you'll need to set the prefer header.

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc453752234, section 8.2.8.7

`.Header("prefer", "return=representation")`

Comment: Prefer header is supported for Planner. This approach will have the latest data for the task details returned (including your requested change).

Answer (score 1):

I wondered if trying to re-use the retrieved `PlannerTaskDetails` object was causing the "set twice" behavior I was seeing with the Description property.

I tweaked my code to create a new `PlannerTaskDetails` object, while still using the e-tag from the retrieved `PlannerTaskDetails` object, and this time the only properties in the JSON body was a single instance of the Description property with my desired value.

```
var previousTaskDetails = taskDetailsResult.Result; // Get Previous Task Details
var newTaskDetails = new PlannerTaskDetails();
newTaskDetails.Description = description;

task.Details = await graphServiceClient
    .Planner
    .Tasks[task.Id]
    .Details
    .Request()
    .Header("If-Match", previousTaskDetails.GetEtag())
    .UpdateAsync(newTaskDetails);
```

`UpdateAsync` still returns a null object, so if I wanted to return the latest `PlannerTaskDetails` object along with the `PlannerTask` object the number API calls is now up to 4:

- Create Task.
- Retrieve TaskDetails.
- Update TaskDetails.
- Retrieve  TaskDetails.